# How to completely hide off-screen in an android app game developed in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am developing an android app game in unity and wanted to completely hide the off-screen area, so I installed a clear camera separate from the camera used to view the game.

[image: Setting of Camera for Clearing in unity editor]

However, when I actually build it on android, I see a small text "development" in the lower right corner as shown in the image.

[image: text "developer build" show up!]

Do you know of a setting that would prevent this kind of text from showing up? Or is this only seen in developer builds?

Comment: the text "Development Build" is only visible in development builds. if you publish a regular build there wont be any text in the corner.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the "Development Build" is only shown if you built the project with the checkmark of "Development build", so:

1. it won't show in regular builds
2. Unclick the option and you will see how your game looks in a complete build, but you won't be able to debug properly.